# Admin login issues

Tags: users

I have checked 'admin' user's status is currently 1 which means its active. I have tried to retrieve password via email also but I have not received any email may be because I am hosting in local.

I have reset the password from sql using below query

```sql
 update users set pass = md5('mynwepass') where uid = 1;
```

It seems like it updated  the password but Drupal isn't recognizing my new password. I have repeatedly tried and my admin id got blocked temporarily and then I truncated the flood table to let me retry. But still it doesn't recognize my credentials.

Is there any other option left other than reinstall Drupal?

Comment: What version of Drupal you are using?

Comment: To activate mail system in local host, open the php.ini and set "SMTP = mail.example.com" . configure the smtp, so that you can get the email.

Comment: i am still not receiving emails. my outgoing server require authentication. any more settings to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal does not store passwords as md5. It is salted hash now, to prevent rainbow attacks.

If you need to be able to manually set password, without a need for working mail system, your best bet is to use [Drush](http://drush.ws/) - a command line shell and scripting interface for Drupal.

```sh
drush user-password someuser --password="correct horse battery staple"
```

Answer (score 1):

You better change your password:

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* The PHP page that serves all page requests on a Drupal installation.
*
* The routines here dispatch control to the appropriate handler, which then
* prints the appropriate page.
*
* All Drupal code is released under the GNU General Public License.
* See COPYRIGHT.txt and LICENSE.txt.
*/
/**
* Root directory of Drupal installation.
*/
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
require_once 'includes/password.inc';
echo user_hash_password('givenpassword');
die();
menu_execute_active_handler();
?>
```

after changing the pass delete that lines which are responsible to change password.
You can see the solution by this link: [Reset admin password](https://drupal.org/node/992400)